# Detect if bud earphones are in ear

Tags: resistance, measurement, speakers, headphones, pressure

- I have bud earphones, through which I am listening to music.
- Air pressure in my ear (after inserting the earphones) is presumably slightly higher than the pressure of the surrounding air outside of my ears.
- Based on that observation, is it *hypothetically* possible to detect (eg. via resistance of the earphones) whether they are in my ears or not? (Assuming there's some sound being played through them.) If so, what would need to be measured / what measuring devices would be needed?

I'm not asking for a interface-specific solution eg. for 3.5mm jack earphones, I'm just curious as to whether there is such possibility in general (for some/any interface).

Comment: There are audionic (sic?) test devices used by hearing specialists that measure the compliance of the membranes and bones in the middle ear by sending (very?) low frequency signals into the ear canal and monitoring the return loss or something.  So in theory detecting may be possible with sensitive instruments though using air pressure may turn out to be unreliable and unpleasant.  I have a pair of ear buds where one makes an air tight seal and the other does not, the one that seals is horrid because the thin diaphragm keeps crackling if I move my jaw. I keep meaning to perforate the membrane.

Comment: Maybe you can use them as microphones and listen for a (heart)beat?

Comment: @try-catch-finally Only if i didn't want to use them as headphones as well, which I do. Besides, I don't think the heartbeat would be loud enough, since you don't hear it by your own ears.

Comment: You may switch the earphones from an amplifier output to an amplifier input during _silent phases_. Maybe you could elaborate on the application a bit more (is it supposed to pause music when plugging out the earbuds, e.g.)?

Comment: @try-catch-finally It's supposed to pause the music when I take the earbuds out of my ears. The whole point is to make using headphones with phone/PC more convenient. When you need to take them out, you usually also want to pause the music if it's playing, so it would be nice if the device (phone or PC) could figure out whether you have them in your ears or not. It certainly would not be convenient for me to manually switch between input and output during "silent phases" (whatever you precisely mean by that).

Answer (score 1):

If the ear buds were perfectly sealed and inserted with a perfect seal, there may be slight changes in impedance measurable by swept frequency impedance analyzer, but since the air load pressure is slight compared to the source pressure, it might be very small like putting a 100k resistor in parallel with 100 ohms.

If you sealed the ear bud up tight, it would be more noticeable without much volume of air.  If the ear bud was submerged in water for example ( not recommended) then a less compliant load would increase the current wave somewhat and the pressure and make it more measurable from the change.

The compliance or change in diaphragm volume relative to the volume of air in the ear canal is what might affect the impedance.  Typically The impedance goes down to 50% at DC or if the diaphragm was prevented from displacement with something.  The stall current in DC linear voice coil can be as low as 10% of the AC impedance (at some rated power) but for speakers it is closer 50%.